# Porque me da de resultado, violacion de segmento?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int contador_caracteres(char* cadena, char caracter);

int main(void){


    char letra;
    int cont;
    char mensaje[100] = "esto es una prueba";
    
    printf("Introduce un caracter de la A a la Z\n");
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    
    printf("Numero de apariciones: %d", contador_caracteres(mensaje,letra));

}

int contador_caracteres(char *cadena, char caracter)
{

    int i;
    int contador = 0;

    if(strlen(cadena) != 0)
    {
        for(i=0;9 < strlen(cadena); i++)
        {
            if (caracter == cadena[i])
            {
                contador = contador + 1;
            }
        }
    }
return contador;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu condición de termino es

```
9 < strlen(cadena)
```

y `cadena` mide 18 de largo.

La condición siempre será verdadera, pues `cadena` no cambia de largo. Por tanto, `i` se incrementa sin parar, hasta el infinito y más allá.

Probablemente debas escribir

```
for(i=0; cadena[i]; i++)
```

para detenerte cuando llegues al final de `cadena`.

Comment: *hasta el infinito y más allá..* esa frase me recuerda a *Buzz Lightyear* xD